# Merging Column results to as a parameter in paginated reports

Tags: powerbi, reportbuilder, powerbi-paginated-reports

I would like to separate Dublin to other cities like Manchester, St Albans (grouped as UK). How should I do this? There's no country data for this [image]

I have tried adding the city from query designer, and editing the available values as "specify values" is not working

Comment: Please accept the answer, if this answers your query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a new DAX measure  column , with a condition such as

```
NewCountryColumn = IF(Table[Location] = 'Dublin', 'IRELAND', 'UK')
```

Then you'll see a new measure column, which will have IRELAND for DUBLIN and rest all will be shown as UK , use this column to do your filter.